# Board-tile game click event OOP pattern

Tags: java, object-oriented, game, swing, minesweeper

This is actually an old 'problem' that I never really knew how to improve, but I'm wondering now if there is a better approach for this problem.

I'm creating MineSweeper with Java and struggling with an OOP aspect of the game. Basically I have a class `Square.java`, `SquareBoms`(`extends Square`) and `Field.java`. My approach on the `Square` is that it should only be aware of itself and should not communicate in any way or form with the `Field`.

However, the `Field` should check the surrounding `SquaresBombs` for bombs once a Square has been clicked. So the `Square` SHOULD message the `Field` that it has been clicked, but I don't think this is the right way of using OOP.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Square extends JButton {
    Field owner; //This is not OOP as the Square should only be aware of itself and what is in it.
    int coords;
    boolean isChecked = false;
    boolean isMarked = false;
    int bombsAround;

    public Square(Field owner, int coords) {
        this.owner = owner;
        this.coords = coords;
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                    Clicked();
                } 
                else if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                    Mark();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void Clicked() {
        if(!isChecked) {
            this.setBackground(new Color(238, 238, 238)); // Reset when it had been marked
            isChecked = true;
            this.setEnabled(false);

            owner.checkSquare(this); //This is not OOP as the Square should only be aware of itself and what is in it.
        }
    }

    public void Mark() {
        if(!isChecked) {
            if(!isMarked)
                this.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            else
                this.setBackground(null);

            isMarked = !isMarked; // toggle on every click
        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

My original question was if it was 'allowed' to let a child object know about its parent. After doing some research i've come to the conclusion that this is not wrong in pure OOP-terms.

Comment: What is a `Field`?  How is a `Field` different from a `Square`?

Comment: @JS1 `Field` is the playing board which contains `Squares` as in playing tiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Separation of Logic and Rendering**

The `Square` object is essentially a button that also contains some information for display, such as the number of surrounding bombs.

The problem you are having is that this GUI element is communicating directly with the game board of your minesweeper game model.  When `Square` gets clicked, it tells the board to check the amount of bombs.

I'm not very familiar with Swing, but typically I would expect there to be a Scene or Window at the top level of the hierarchy.  Once clicked, the button would tell the controller to tell the game model to perform the necessary action, and then the controller would update the view based on changes to the model.

In this approach you could possibly have a `Game` object, `Board` object, and `Square` object in the game model. On a button click, the coordinates of the `Square` button object in the view would be passed into the `Game`, and the appropriate changes would be made to the `Board` and to the game state.  For example, the coordinates have a bomb, and so the state of the `Game` is set to GameState.LOSS.

In this approach, you could make the `Board` object available to the view. 
After each move, the view could update based on the new state of the board, marking the squares that have flags, have been uncovered, etc.

You could also do something such as compute the positions of the nearby `Square` objects at the start of the game, and then you could check for bombs like this:

```
int bombCount = 0;
for (Position position : square.neighbors) {
    Square neighbor = board.get(position);
    if (neighbor.hasBomb) {
        bombCount++;
    }
}
```

Or alternatively store a reference to the actual `Square` objects, if you want.

The advantage of all of this is that if you some day want to use a different graphical representation other than Swing, you could easily take the code for the game model and use a different controller and view. You would still use the model in the same way, passing in the coordinates of the location on the board that is clicked.

Comment: Thank you for this insightful post! I see now by creating a controller(logic) for the `Squares` the `Square` itself isn't aware of the `Field` anymore, which is good. However, do you mean to instantiate the controller for every `Square` or use one `Controller` for all the `Squares` which communicates from `Square -> Controller -> Field`.

Comment: What I am suggesting is that the `Controller` would have an array of `Buttons` that make up the GUI and correspond to the `Square` objects in the model, and then the `Controller` would also have a `Game` object which has a `Board` object which contains the `Square` objects. Pressing a `Button` would cause the `Controller` to pass a command to the `Game`.